# beginDelayedTransition does not work, showing only the final view position

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to move button to the center, show it , then move to the corner.

But it won't move, it immediately appears in the corner. Why?

**upd** Android 5.1, API 22.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                // remember true position/size
                final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams_= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mapFollowButton.getLayoutParams();
                // create temp position/size from which will move
                final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (150*density), (int) (150*density));
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
                mapFollowButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                mapFollowButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mapFollowButton.invalidate();

                final ChangeBounds transition= new ChangeBounds();
                transition.setDuration(1000L); 
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainRL),transition);
                //here expected to move to true position from center
                mapFollowButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams_);
                mapFollowButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else
                mapFollowButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, I've found a solution. Works, but strangely enough, this nowhere mentioned. Just need to make a pause, even 10ms. The rest the same.

```
                ....
                //mapFollowButton.invalidate();

                mapFollowButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                            final ChangeBounds transition= new ChangeBounds();
                            transition.setDuration(1000L); 
                            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainRL),transition);
                        }
                        mapFollowButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams_);
                        mapFollowButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                },10);
```

Comment: and for XY do not use setX(), use layoutParams.setMargins()